# About function namespace in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

**In a.py)**

```
def pool_init():
    global aa
    aa = "I'm in a.py"

def pool_func(chunk, job_func):
    return job_func(chunk)

def run_pool(mp_iterable, job_func, pool_func = pool_func):
    rst = []
    partial(pool_func, job_func = job_func)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=pool_init,) as p:
        for ir in p.imap_unordered(pool_func, mp_iterable):
            rst.append(ir)
```

**In main.py)**

```
def job_func():
    print(aa)

a.run_pool(range(5), job_func = job_func)
```

raised (in Cent OS, jupyter)

`NameError: name 'aa' is not defined`

**Questions)**

1. Why did this error occured?
2. How could i fix this error?

**Edit)**
Recently, I need multiprocessing module more often, so I wanted to make some functions to run multiprocessing.Pool in my custom module not to write redundant codes.

I want to run multiprocessing.Pool just like:

```
run_pool(iterable, job_func)
# Acutal processes in job_func, the both arguments are defined in main.py
```

Comment: In your a.py you must declare a variable aa in the top level. Like `aa= ""`  then in your main.py do `import aa from a`. But you should not have globals like this. And don't name your variables and files `a`, `aa`, give them descriptive names.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, wouldn't this need `aa` to be also defined outside of `pool_init` ?

Comment: Yes, in my comment I mention that in the first line

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, completly missed the first sentence. Sorry

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki no, `import aa from a` won't work. That isn't the correct syntax, but also, you need to use the module namespace for this to work. But regardless of all of that, multiprocessing *does not share state*

Comment: "Why did this error occured?" This has nothing to do with multiprocessing, these are the very normal scoping ruels in Python. But note, multiple processes **will not share state**, though, when you fix this error you are going to have to deal with that